# How to tell Spring manage autowired dependencies in my library?

Tags: spring, maven

I have a reusable component that right now uses Spring in order to be properly instantiated, that means that Spring will autowire all the dependencies that my component needs. I want to make this component a maven module and import it to other projects. All the projects that will use this library are using Spring as Dependency Injector. Can Spring still manage the dependencies for my maven module or do I need to do that manually.Are there any best practices for such scenarios? What I basically asking is how to tell spring to manage the dependencies of my library.

Comment: The exact same way as if the components were in the application itself: by declaring the beans in XML, in Java config, or by annotating it and scanning its package.

Comment: @JBNizet Make it an answer!